# Why solving the cubic is important?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, motivation

Why people in sixteenth century (or the people now ) interested in solving the cubic?
There were (I think) no number theoretic or relation to science that time, and the only impression I get from reading books is that they did it to one-up other persons on competitions.

That's not a mathematical Motivation. What was the mathematical Motivation ? In twenty first century, what's the motivation to do that ?

Comment: Curiosity is certainly a mathematical motivation, one which still exists sometimes in the twenty-first century.

Comment: Also see [What is an example of real application of cubic equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825699/what-is-an-example-of-real-application-of-cubic-equations).

Comment: The roots of a cubic equation exhibit some circumstances that do not occur with a quadratic equation.  For a brief historical account see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).  Of particular interest is the [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis) or "irreducible case".  The possibility arises that a cubic polynomial has three distinct real roots, but complex numbers are necessary in order to express these "by radicals".

Answer (score 2):

Natural to try this after solving quadratic equations.  You're just going up 1 degree.   Then there's the quartic;  and degree 5 and higher have no closed form...